# Query about shared library performance

Tags: performance, shared

I have a question about performance difference (from the perspective of Cycles consumed) between a static library and shared library(windows - dll).

I have a static library for some code. I also have a dynamic library for the same code. 
I have linked these two libraries to a application.

Will there be any difference in performance(Cycles consumed,Cache hits/missed, etc..) if I profile the two libraries.(Profiling conditions, parameters are same for both libraries)

If yes, what could be the causes for the differences in performances of the two?

Thank You.

-AD.

Answer (score 1):

Once the routines in the DLL have been thunked in, there is no performance difference other than an additional CALL/RET when calling them.